# Correct design procedure for UART cross

Tags: uart

I'm designing a circuit with a uP (5V logic), Bluetooth module (3V3 logic) and a voltage level translator (TXS0102). 
Is it up to my consideration on where to do the cross-over? 3V3 side or the 5V side.

Comment: What is "the cross-over"?

Comment: TX to RX and vise versa.

Comment: It doesn't matter, but what I would suggest is thinking about debugging and which voltage is more convenient to add the test points to. Also labelling since "TX" and "RX" are relative.

Comment: Replace the 5v MCU with a better performing modern 3v3 one.  Since you have a 3v3 component in the system you've lost the main remaining advantage of a 5v one.  Doubly so if that only has one hardware UART...

Comment: If by "cross over" you mean tx/rx switch, realize that from the perspective of the TXS0102 there is no such thing as tx or rx, only the A side and the B side.  What you do need to pay attention to is the requirement that the B side be the higher voltage one.

Comment: I still don't follow. You connect the output of one chip to the input of the other, and vice-versa, through the translator as needed. Are you asking where on the schematics do the signal names change? That's entirely up to you. There is no one "correct" answer.